# How do I find out how many ethernet ports my PC's motherboard supports?

Tags: networking, motherboard, ethernet

I have a Desktop PC (Core i5 processor, [GA-B85M-D3H Gigabyte motherboard](http://www.gigabyte.in/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4567#sp)). I want to expand the system to support 4 ethernet ports. (1 incoming, 3 outgoing ports connected to 3 different ISPs for load balancing).

How do I find out how many ethernet ports can my motherboard support? Official specifications do not talk about it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific limit.

On a modern motherboard you have PCI-e slots and optionally a few build in Ethernet ports.

In each PCI-e slot you can add an expansion cards. That can be a traditional cheap NIC with one port, or more server orientated cards. Many of these feature 4 ports.

Thus, without doing anything exotic:

- Count the number of ports already on the motherboard.
- Count the number of free PCI-e slots.
- Calculate first + 4x second.

As to exotic: The can use PCI-e to multiple PCI-2 bridges.

[image: Example of a regular 4 ports NIC:]

---

Thus far the generic answer.  Now for your specific setup:

Your board has one on board NIC, three PCI-e conectors and two ancient PCI-connectors. In theory you could have up to 21 Ethernet ports.

That is assuming no other cards are in use, and using PCI rather than PCI-e is not recommended (it is a shared bus with relative low bandwith, you you can put a quad card in it, but a single 1Gbit NIC can saturate a 33Mhz/32bit PCI bus).